# How to Fix a Column Using a For Loop and Placing into Another Column Using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pasted the code below. Need to fix the accountant name and making each variation them same (doesn't matter which variation, as long each are the same). I figured there were 2 options,1) using a dictionary or 2) trying to fix the name based upon matching the first 3 letters of the Accountant Name.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Accountant Name':
            ['Sindman Traub LLP', 'Sindman Traub LLC', 'Sindman Traub PLLC',
             'McCrumb & Assoc.', 'McCrumb & Associates LLC', 'Lee & Mike',
             'Lee & Mike LLC', 'Lee & Mike Inc','Sindman Traub Corp'],
        'Cost':[10, 9, 15, 4, 13, 25, 2, 89, 44]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['AverageCost'] =np.nan
df['Fixed Accountant Name'] =np.nan
df = df.sort_values(by=['Accountant Name'], ascending = True)
```

Output =

```
outputdata = {'Accountant Name':['Sindman Traub LLP', 'Sindman Traub LLC', 'Sindman Traub PLLC',
                                 'McCrumb & Assoc.', 'McCrumb & Associates LLC', 'Lee & Mike',
                                 'Lee & Mike LLC', 'Lee & Mike Inc','Sindman Traub Corp'],
              'Cost':[10, 9, 15, 4, 13, 25, 2, 89, 44],
              'Fixed Accountant Name':['Sindman Traub', 'Sindman Traub','Sindman Traub',
                                       'McCrumb and Associates', 'McCrumb and Associates',
                                       'Lee and Mike','Lee and Mike', 'Lee and Mike', 'Sindman Traub'],
              'AverageCost':[19.500000, 19.500000,19.500000,8.500000,8.500000, 38.666667,38.666667,38.666667,19.500000]}
outputdf = pd.DataFrame(outputdata)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean fix it? what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, so please post expected output.

Maybe this?:

```
df['Fixed Accountant Name'] = [x[:3] for x in df['Accountant Name']]
df.groupby('Fixed Accountant Name')['Cost'].mean()
Fixed Accountant Name
Lee    38.666667
McC     8.500000
Sin    19.500000
```

Comment: Thanks, for the ask. I posted the output code and picture above.

Comment: Can you explain this part of your code? I wasn't sure what this is doing. [x[:3] for x in df['Accountant Name']]

Comment: it takes the first 3 characters of the `Accountant Name` column